# Does std::optional copy an object containing a std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++17, stdoptional

I'm trying to return a `std::optional` to an object containing a `std::unique_ptr` member. However, when I try to change the `optional` return type to use a reference, I get errors like this:

> error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type std::optional<ObjectWithConnection>& to an rvalue of type std::optional<ObjectWithConnection>

**Is this the best way to return `_aConnection` without encountering any copying/latency across the stack frames?**

I use references very often, but I've never used `std::optional` with `std::unique_ptr` and I'm concerned what it's doing under the hood.

```
struct ObjectWithConnection
{
    std::unique_ptr<Connection> _aConnection;
};

struct ConnectionsContainer
{
    // If I change return type to reference, get compiler error
    std::optional<ObjectWithConnection> getConnection(const std::string& key)
    {
        auto iter = _connections.find(key);
        if(iter != _connections.end())
        {
            return std::optional<ObjectWithConnection>(std::move(iter->second));
        }

        return std::nullopt;
    }

    std::unordered_map<std::string, ObjectWithConnection> _connections;
}

struct AnotherClass
{
    // If I change return type to reference, get compiler error
    std::optional<ObjectWithConnection> getConnection(const std::string& key)
    {
        return _container.getConnection(key);
    }

    ConnectionsContainer _container;
};
```

Comment: `return std::optional<ObjectWithConnection>(std::move(iter->second));` returns a temporary `std::optional`. If you declare the return type as a reference you will return a dangling reference as the temporary `std::optional` which has been destroyed.

Comment: But, just in case: what exactly does "change the optional return type to use a reference" mean? When asking about code that doesn't work, it's more helpful to show the actual code that doesn't work, instead of different code that does work.

Comment: A function named `get` should probably not be changing the container. If you `std::move` an object of `_connections` when you `getConnection` means you can only ever `getConnection` up to once per `key`. The next time you try the `ObjectWithConnection` will already have been moved out. Unless the goal is for `get` to transfer ownership entirely, consider just returning a `ObjectWithConnection*` instead.

Answer (score -1):

There are no std::optional references. A program is ill-formed if it instantiates an optional with a reference type. Alternatively, an optional of a std::reference_wrapper of type T may be used to hold a reference.

Comment: See the error message in the question - `error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type std::optional<ObjectWithConnection>&`

Comment: @RichardCritten How about this sentence in description: **However, when I try to change the optional return type to use a reference, i get errors like this**?